# Existence of positive real number whose square is $a$?

Tags: real-analysis

My book proves the existence of a positive real number whose square is $a$, where $a>0$.
Proof: Let $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^+|x^2 \le a\}$. Now the completeness property of $\mathbb{R}$ implies that supremum of $S$ exists. So let $u=\text{sup}(S)$. Note that $u>0$.

To prove the existence, we need to show that $u^2=a$. We also need to show that set $S$ is bounded above. Now we know by completeness property of $R$ that set $S$ is bounded above so we let u=$sup(S)$. I wanted to know why $u^2 = a $ proves the existence of such positive numbers. Now after reading comments and answers I reached to a conclusion i.e if $u^2$ is not equal to a or if $u$ is not equal to $ \sqrt{a }$, the it contradicts our assumption that supremum of set $S$ exists in $R^+$ .
Now my other doubt is the way we choose the set $S$ itself assumed that such number exists and its belongs to set $S$. So I want to know is this a valid way to prove ? Because we already assumed the existence such number. I think the if we choose set $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^+|x^2 < a\}$ then proof is valid.

Comment: If for any $a>0$ there is a $u>0$ with $u^2=a$ then that says there is a positive real number whose square is $a$, namely $u$

Comment: the stated proof is wrong, as you need to show that $S$ is not empty and bounded to say that it have a supremum

Comment: You also want $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^+\mid x^2<a\}$, not $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^+\mid x^2=a\}$.

Comment: If $u$ exists and is a positive real number and its square is $a$ then what does that say about the existence of a positive real number whose square is $a$? In what other way can you parse the statement that is to be proved? (The flaws in how we got to that step of the proof are another matter.)

Comment: Yes Arthur its my mistake now I have edited my question.

Comment: You don't understand how $u^2=a$ proves there exists a number whose square is $a$? Is it the "positive" part that gives you trouble?

Comment: My trouble is what is the relation between existence of positive number whose square is a and the supremum of the set S? In other words why we need supremum of set S to prove the existence of the number ? I am missing here something . I am unable to connect supremum and existence of number

Comment: You might wish to reword your final sentence. From your latest comment, it seems that you *do* understand that **once it is proved that** $u>0$ and $u^2=a$, "the existence of a positive number whose square is $a$" immediately follows. So your question, it seems, is **how to prove that** $u>0$ and $u^2=a$.

Comment: " why we need supremum of set S to prove the existence of the number ? I am missing here something "  Well, that's because the proof hasn't been done yet.   We have the set $S$.  And the book is claiming that $u =\sup S$ exists.  Now the task we have to prove (but which *hasn't* been proven yet) is that $u^2 =a$.  So far there is nothing in the definition of $S$ and $u=\sup S$ that indicates that $u^2=a$. But ***WHEN*** we prove that we will be done.  We will have found that $\sup S$ was just the number we need.

Comment: Ah... I see your problem "To prove the existence, we need to show that $u^2=a$".  No.  You don't need to $u^2=a$ in order to prove $u$ exists.  We *know* $u = \sup S$ exists by completeness theorem.  But we don't (yet) know what $u^2$ is equal to.  Once we show that $u^2$ does indeed equal $a$ *then* we will have shown that a real number whose square is $a$ does exist .... because $u$ is just such a number.

Comment: Maybe you should think of it this way.  A professor asks "does there exist a real number whose square is $a$".  I answer. "I don't know. I'm going to do something else. Let's take a walk in a park.  By the way I like this set $S$.  And $u =\sup S$ exists.  I wonder what $u^2$ is equal to.... Hmm, doing stuff, I see that $u^2 = a$.  Hmm, I guess $u$ is a number whose square is $a$... That means there is such a number because $u$ is just such a number.  I'm done with your proof".

Comment: May I ask why this question is getting downvoted?

Comment: I did not downvote, although I can tell you why I was tempted to: the question is quite unclear, and the OP did not take any of the multiple hints offered in the comments to clarify the question. The effect of this lack of clarity is clear from the comments and the answers: we potential answerers are left to speculate and make guesses regarding what, exactly, the poster wants or needs to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering to the questions you posted in the comments and the post. You need to understand what motivates the set $S$ and then you will understand your other question on the comments on why do we need the $\sup S$.

The proof relies on the fact that you can't just take $\sqrt{a}$ because you don't know its existence, so you phrase the question on terms of things you know exist but are related to the problem you have. You need to fabricate that number $u$ and the completeness property gives you an object which exists. So instead of asking *which is the square root of a* you ask for those numbers whose squares are less than $a$. Why? because you can always square things, and you *"know"* from working with these things that if any number will satisfy the condition of $u^2=a$ then it must be the supremum of those numbers, as squaring is an increasing function. Besides, if any number surpasses $a$ when squaring, you know that number is not going to be on the set $S$ nor any of those greater than it.

That is the reason you take the set $S$ and why you choose the supremum (you must prove it is non-empty and bounded for the supremum to actually exist, which is not hard to prove). Now with regards to actually proving that idea you had works, you use the continuity of squaring to prove that $u=\sup S$ must fulfill with $u^2=a$. If it were $u^2< a$ or $u^2>a$ then there is space for you to disprove this is actually a supremum (I know this last comment might be a little vague, but it is for you to think about it and ultimately ask in the comments)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it would be conceptually easier of you take a special case, like $a = 2$.

$u = \sup S$ is the smallest upper bound of $S$.

Then I think it's fairly clear that

$$ u^2 < 2$$

is impossible, as $u$ wouldn't be an upper bound, and

$$ u^2 > 2$$

is impossible, as $u$, in that case, would be an upper bound, but not the smallest such.

Only one option remains.